# Django return home page in get absolute url

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

My PostCreateView

```
class PostCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Posts
    template_name = "blog/post_form.html"
    fields = ["author", "title", "content"]
```

My urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='blog-home'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='blog-about'),
    path("post/new/", PostCreateView.as_view(), name="post-create"),
]
```

Once I do a post my site crashes since I need to specify a get_absolute_url. I just want to return to the home page but trying

```
redirect("") fails with error


 NoReverseMatch at /post/new/
 Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

How can I return to the homepage ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redirect to the view with the given *name*, so:

```
redirect('blog-home')  # since name='blog-home'
```

or if you work with a class-based view which has a `FormMixin` like a `CreateView`, `UpdateView`, etc. you reverse with:

```
from django.urls import reverse

class PostCreateView(CreateView):
    # …

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('blog-home')
```

Comment: TypeError at /post/new/
quote_from_bytes() expected bytes

Comment: Can you share the `PostCreateView`? edit the question

Comment: @OnePiece: exactly where is the `redirect` in your view(s)?